# Регулярное для простой get-переменной в файле urls

Tags: регулярные-выражения, django

Привет. У меня есть регулярное выражение `\?var=([^\W_]{10})$` для ссылок вида ?var=r4gu7b71r2 и оно работает.
Нужно просто вставить его в файл urls.py.
Вставляю `url(r'^\?var=([^\W_]{10})$', views.index, name='index')` - не работает. Но работает без знака ? `url(r'^var=([^\W_]{10})$',` для ссылок var=r4gu7b71r2.

Как в django вставить такой url?

Comment: URL-паттерны предназначены только для путей и не обрабатывают параметры.

Comment: Неужели в django нельзя проверять такие урлы? Как тогда здесь лучше сделать?

Comment: Проверять их в представлении.